# How can I bind MenuItem's Text (and if possible IconImageSource)?

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

I have a .Net MAUI app. I define a menu in AppShell.xaml. One MenuItem is this:

```
    <MenuItem Text="{Binding LoginText}"
          IconImageSource="{Binding LoginIcon}"
          Command="{Binding ToggleLoginCommand}" />
```

I set binding context in AppShell.xaml.cs:

```
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = new Menu();
    ...
```

This is the Menu class:

```
public partial class Menu : ObservableObject
{
    protected const string _textSignIn = "Sign In";
    protected const string _textSignOut = "Sign Out";
    protected const string _iconSignIn = "IconSignIn";
    protected const string _iconSignOut = "IconSignOut";
...
    public Menu()
    {
        _loginIcon = App.IsLoggedIn ? _iconSignOut : _iconSignIn;
        _loginText = App.IsLoggedIn ? _textSignOut : _textSignIn;
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _loginIcon;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _loginText;

...
    [ICommand]
    protected async Task ToggleLoginAsync()
    {
        ...
        _loginIcon = App.IsLoggedIn ? _iconSignOut : _iconSignIn;
        _loginText = App.IsLoggedIn ? _textSignOut : _textSignIn;
        ...
    }
```

In Styles.xaml:

```
<FontImage x:Key="IconSignIn"
           FontFamily="FontAwesome"
           Size="22"
           Color="{StaticResource LaticreteColor}"
           Glyph="{x:Static local:IconFont.SignInAlt}"/>
<FontImage x:Key="IconSignOut"
           FontFamily="FontAwesome"
           Size="22"
           Color="{StaticResource LaticreteColor}"
           Glyph="{x:Static local:IconFont.SignOutAlt}"/>
```

In the hamburger menu, the text is always "Sign In", and after _loginText is changed, the MenuItem looks the same.

And the icon doesn't show up at all. What is missing?

ADDED:

Here is the generated property:

```
     /// <inheritdoc cref="_loginText"/>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.ObservablePropertyGenerator", "8.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public string LoginText
    {
        get => _loginText;
        set
        {
            if (!global::System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(_loginText, value))
            {
                OnLoginTextChanging(value);
                OnPropertyChanging(global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.__Internals.__KnownINotifyPropertyChangingArgs.LoginText);
                _loginText = value;
                OnLoginTextChanged(value);
                OnPropertyChanged(global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.__Internals.__KnownINotifyPropertyChangedArgs.LoginText);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are setting `_loginText` which is the **private field**, not the **public property** `LoginText` which triggers a `PropertyChanged` event

Comment: @Jason That is because I use CommunityToolkit.mvvm. It generates observable property from the private field. Please see my update.

Comment: I understand that.  But in `ToggleLoginAsync` you are not setting the public property, so you are not triggering `PropertyChanged`

Comment: @Jason Great, thank you! After I assign the changed value to LoginText, it changes correctly. Maybe you could tell why the icon doesn't show up, even initially (after I apply your fix, of course)?

Comment: I'd try hardcoding the value in the XAML just to verify that you are using the correct name, the image is valid, etc

Comment: @Jason It shows up if I use Static Resource: IconImageSource="{StaticResource IconSignIn}". But how can I bind it?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/45292333/199364

Comment: The cause is when you set the `Image.Source` 's value as a string, it will call the `ImageSource.From(string file)`. But the _iconSignIn's value is the key in the `Style.xaml` not a file name. In addition, the `FontImage` can't be declared in the code behind. So it seems you can't get the instance of it in the `Menu.cs` from the `Style.xaml`. You may have to use two image file instead of the `FontImage` in the `Style.xaml`.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT It is not clear to me. Are you suggesting using images instead of FontAwesome?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve That solution is about images, and I am dealing with a font FontAwesome... Do you think it may be applicable?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve OK, I use .png now instead of the font. <MenuItem Text="{Binding LoginText}" IconImageSource="{Binding LoginIcon}" Command="{Binding ToggleLoginCommand}" /> It works great. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason As you gave me a fix for my initial question, would you like to make it an answer? I would mark it as such. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, using the images instead of FontAwesome is easy to bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing this

```
protected async Task ToggleLoginAsync()
{
    ...
    _loginIcon = App.IsLoggedIn ? _iconSignOut : _iconSignIn;
    _loginText = App.IsLoggedIn ? _textSignOut : _textSignIn;
    ...
}
```

`_loginText` is a **private field** and does not raise `PropertyChanged`.  In order to raise `PropertyChanged` you need to set the **public property**

```
LoginText = App.IsLoggedIn ? _textSignOut : _textSignIn;
```