# Shell FlyoutItem icon from Font Awesome

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, .net-maui.shell

I am trying to use FontAwesome icons in `FlyoutItem` as an icon using `FontImageSource`. I had success in Xamarin Forms with following setup, but for some reason in NET MAUI it does not work (at least on Windows?)? I am seeing tab item, but there is no icon no matter what I try. Is there some way to use Font Awesome icons instead of png pictures?

Example of icon I am trying to use: https://fontawesome.com/icons/user?s=solid&f=classic

MauiProgram.cs:

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
  .UseSkiaSharp(true)
  .UseMauiApp<App>()
  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
  {
    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
    fonts.AddFont("FW-Regular-400.otf", "FontAwesomeRegular");
    fonts.AddFont("FWBrands-Regular-400.otf", "FontAwesomeBrands");
    fonts.AddFont("FW-Solid-900.otf", "FontAwesomeSolid");
  });
```

App.xaml:

```
  <!-- Desktop/Tablet-->
  <FlyoutItem Title="Home">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:HomePage}">
      <ShellContent.Icon>
        <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="&#xf021;"/>
      </ShellContent.Icon>
    </ShellContent>
  </FlyoutItem>
  <FlyoutItem Title="Settings">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:SettingsPage}">
      <ShellContent.Icon>
        <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="user"/>
      </ShellContent.Icon>
    </ShellContent>
  </FlyoutItem>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you set the build action to `MauiFont`? That's usually the mistake people make

Comment: @FreakyAli build action is set to MauiFont. Also icons are working in application for buttons labels and etc, but for some reason not for FlyoutItems in App.xaml

Comment: You might wanna check if this is an open bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have got it working way mentioned below. However currently it seems that this solution is working in NET7, but not in NET6. In NET6 there are no icons visible:

[image]

---

**For NET 7**

**App.xaml:**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyTool"
             xmlns:page="clr-namespace:MyTool.Pages"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:MyTool.Helpers"
             x:Class="MyTool.App">

  <Application.MainPage>
    <Shell FlyoutWidth="90" FlyoutBehavior="{OnIdiom Phone=Disabled, Default=Locked}">

      <!-- Desktop/Tablet-->
      <FlyoutItem Title="Home" Icon="{FontImage FontFamily=FontAwesomeSolid, Glyph={x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.House}, Size=50}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:HomePage}">
          <ShellContent.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.House}" Color="White" Size="50"/>
          </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
      </FlyoutItem>
      <FlyoutItem Title="Settings" Icon="{FontImage FontFamily=FontAwesomeSolid, Glyph={x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.Gear}, Size=50}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:SettingsPage}">
          <ShellContent.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.Gear}" Color="White" Size="50"/>
          </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
      </FlyoutItem>
    </Shell>
  </Application.MainPage>
</Application>
```

**FontAwesomeIcons.cs:**
(use some tool available in Internet for such a class generation)

```
namespace MyTool.Helpers
{
    public static class FontAwesomeIcons
    {
      public const string Space = "\u0020";
      public const string Exclamation = "\u0021";
      public const string Hashtag = "\u0023";
      public const string DollarSign = "\u0024";
      public const string Percent = "\u0025";
      public const string Asterisk = "\u002a";
      public const string Plus = "\u002b";
      public const string Hyphen = "\u002d";

      // etc
    }
 }
```

**MauiProgram.cs:**

```
namespace MyTool;

public static class MauiProgram
{
  public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
  {
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
      .UseMauiApp<App>()
      .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
      {
        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
        fonts.AddFont("FW-Solid-900.otf", "FontAwesomeSolid");
      });

#if DEBUG
    builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

    return builder.Build();
  }
}
```

Comment: It is a valid solution. It works and is a common approach. No need for optimization here. It's actually my preferred way, too. That way, you have all the glyphs defined in one place.

Comment: @ewerspej does this work for you in NET6 as well? For me this solution works in NET7, but not in NET6. In NET6 there are no icons or texts visible.

Comment: Not sure, I switched early to .NET 7.0. Do you need to stick with .NET 6.0 for any particular reason?

Comment: @ewerspej I see there are might be some bugs in NET7 as well with NET MAUI. Are you able to change Shell bar background? FlyoutBackground="#111111"
I might ask a new question here

Comment: I mean Flyout background

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but a separate question would indeed be appropriate if it's not directly related to your other issue here

Comment: @ewerspej I have created new question. Maybe you can share some ideas if you have more experience with NET MAUI. Would appreciate. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75006669/change-colour-of-icon-and-text-if-selected-in-sidebar

Answer (score 1):

To be added as an answer to [Shell FlyoutItem icon from Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74977956/shell-flyoutitem-icon-from-font-awesome/75115042#75115042)

Here's one that works for me.
The difference to @10101's answer, and to the one I had above that didn't work is the definition of a static FontIcon resource.
Tested on Net6 and Net7 (VS2022 17.4.4).

It is based on @10101's answer combined with an idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74733391/how-can-i-bind-menuitems-text-and-if-possible-iconimagesource).

**Steps**

- Added a FontIcon resource.
- Set the Icon property on the FlyoutItem (as opposed to the underlying ShellContent).

**Limitation**: the size and color are set on the FontImage resource in the resource definition, not where it is used in FlyoutItem definition. I don't know how to override those properties on the FlyoutItem.

**Code**
Font registration in MauiProgram.cs (abbreviated):

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                [...]
                // Custom fonts
                fonts.AddFont("bootstrap-icons.ttf", "Bootstrap");
            });

            [...]
            return builder.Build();
        }
```

FontIcon created as a resource in styles.xaml (I actually created another resource definition file called fonticons.xaml and added to the merged resource dictionary in App.xaml, but this is not important in this case):

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <x:String x:Key="BootStrapGear">&#xf3e5;</x:String>

    <FontImage x:Key="IconGear"
        FontFamily="Bootstrap"
        Color="Black"
        Size="50"
        Glyph="{x:StaticResource BootStrapGear}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

AppShell.xaml:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="MyApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    [...]
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">
 
    [...]
    <FlyoutItem Title="Settings" Icon="{x:StaticResource IconGear}">
        <ShellContent
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate localconfigns:ConfigPage}"
            Route="ConfigPage" />
    </FlyoutItem>
</Shell>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution works for me:

```
    <FlyoutItem
       Title="Dalle Chalange"
       Icon="{FontImage FontFamily=fontello, 
       Glyph={x:Static FontIcons:IconFont.Compass}, 
       Color=White,
       Size=30}">
       <ShellContent
          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate dalle_views:DashboardView}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

EDIT: Here is same approach but better:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Dalle Chalange">
    <FlyoutItem.FlyoutIcon>
        <FontImageSource
            FontFamily="fontello"
            Glyph="{x:Static FontIcons:IconFont.Compass}"
            Color="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource light_onSurface}, Dark={StaticResource dark_onSurface}}"/>
    </FlyoutItem.FlyoutIcon>
    <ShellContent
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate dalle_views:DashboardView}" />

</FlyoutItem>
```