# Change colour of icon and text if selected in FlyoutItem

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I am trying to implement a sidebar that would have icons from font and while selecting one of them text of Label and Icon colour would change. I was able to implement this partly, but can't figure out how to:

1. Apply background colour to Flyout (currently it is still default black in NET7)
2. Change colour of icon if it is selected (currently colour does not change change on selection)
3. Change colour of Label text if it is selected (currently colour does not change change on selection)

Currently I have this:

[image]

I want to achieve this for selected item also `FlyoutBackground="#111111"` has no effect for some reason:

[image]

**App.xaml:**

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

      <Style x:Key="FloutItemStyle" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
          <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                  <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
                  <Setter TargetName="_label" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Red" />
                  <Setter TargetName="_image" Property="Image.Source" Value="Red" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>

  <Application.MainPage>
    <Shell FlyoutWidth="90" FlyoutBehavior="{OnIdiom Phone=Disabled, Default=Locked}" 
           FlyoutBackground="#111111">

      <Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <BoxView HeightRequest="50" Color="Transparent"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>

      <!-- Desktop/Tablet-->
      <FlyoutItem Title="Home" Icon="{FontImage FontFamily=FontAwesomeSolid, Glyph={x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.User}, Size=50, Color=Red}">
        <ShellContent Title="Page1" Route="Page1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:Page1}">
          <ShellContent.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.User}" Color="Red" Size="50"/>
          </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
      </FlyoutItem>
      <FlyoutItem Title="Settings" Icon="{FontImage FontFamily=FontAwesomeSolid, Glyph={x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.User}, Size=50}">
        <ShellContent Title="Page2" Route="Page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:Page2}">
          <ShellContent.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.User}" Color="White" Size="50"/>
          </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
      </FlyoutItem>

      <Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid Style="{StaticResource FloutItemStyle}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="50" />
              <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   HeightRequest="40"
                   Margin="5,0,5,0"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   x:Name="_image"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="{Binding Title}"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="Body"
                   Padding="7,0,7,0"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   x:Name="_label">
            </Label>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </Shell.ItemTemplate>

    </Shell>
  </Application.MainPage>
```

Comment: You can refer to official doc about [Default template for FlyoutItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-7.0#default-template-for-flyoutitems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Style FlyoutItem and MenuItem objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-7.0#style-flyoutitem-and-menuitem-objects).

In AppShell.xaml:

```
     <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle" TargetType="Label"/>
            <Style TargetType="Image" Class="FlyoutItemImageStyle"/>
            
            <Style x:Key="dd" Class="FlyoutItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark=White,Light=Black}" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemImage" Property="Image.BackgroundColor" Value="white" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Red" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemImage" Property="Image.BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>



   <Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource dd}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   HeightRequest="40"
                   Margin="5,0,5,0"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   x:Name="FlyoutItemImage"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="{Binding Title}"
                   FontSize="Body"
                   Padding="7,0,7,0"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   x:Name="FlyoutItemLabel"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! By the way, does it work for you in NET 7?

Comment: @10101 The project I created before is exactly NET 7.

Comment: Ok, I will try. I see there is an open issue on GitHub at least for Flyout background colour. So was wondering is there some solution to get it working or we need to wait for fix from Microsoft.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12325

Comment: @10101 Yes, you're right. In addition, MAUI Handler may be a way to change Flyout background color. It just like Custom Renderer in Xamarin Forms.